# How do I access a local folder through its filename?

Tags: python, directory, local

I have a folder that is my animation/game, and in the folder is the .pyw file and a .wav music file. I have

```
import wave
wave.open()
```

and I don't know what to put in the parenthesis. I know it is supposed to be the filename, but someone might install the game in an unknown directory. How do I access the local folder through the filename?

The files are in the same folder, and the music is named "Music.wav".

Comment: you should use _os_ functions?

Comment: use `__path__` to determine the path of the current module - The issue BTW is not someone installing it somewhere else, but someone running without doing a cd to where the program is.

Comment: Use a relative not an absolute path

Comment: use a try/except informing the user if the file is missing but if the file is in the same directory it should not matter.

Answer (score 5):

A common way this is done is by using the path of the current module, which is automatically available in the predefined`__file__`variable, to determine the path to the file in the subdirectory:

```
import os
import wave

mydir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
subdir = 'sounds'
wavefilepath = os.path.join(mydir, subdir, 'Music.wav')
wave.open(wavefilepath)
```

Comment: if they are in the same directory why would you need the full path at all?

Comment: @Padraic: Because it's best to not make any assumptions about the current working directory which can be different than the directory that the currently executing module resides is in.

Comment: yes be the current directory name is irrelevant once the once the subdirectory containing the files is in it, the biggest problem would be if the user moved the subdirectory no?

Comment: "file does not start with RIFF id" ?

Comment: @MrSquer: Sounds (no pun intended) like your .wav file is corrupt.

Comment: @Padraic: If the user moved the subdirectory, all bets are off. Sorry, I don't really understand the first part of what you said though...

Comment: @MrSquer: From the error message, it looks like it found the file but it doesn't like what's in it. You can verify it's trying to open the correct file by printing out the value of the computed `wavefilepath`.

Comment: I get no error, but the music does not play. I cannot hear it, and my sound is on. If it helps, I have this saved in a pyw file.

Comment: @Mr Squer: Thought you  meant you were getting a "file does not start with RIFF id" error. The fact that it's a ,pyw file -- which has no stderr or stdout -- may be suppressing the normal display of error messages. Try renaming the file to .py and running it from the command line. You could also just create a little test .py file which does nothing but open and play the wave file.